# Are slashes allowed in URL fragment or query?

Tags: url

My understanding of the general form of a URL is that it looks as follows:

```
<scheme>://<host><path>?<query>#<fragment>
```

Can there be any forward slashes in either the query or the fragment?  More generally, are there any characters that are specifically reserved for any single part of a URL?

Answer (score 8):

*STD 66* defines the [fragment](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.5) as:

> `fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )`

So aside from characters from the `pchar` set (`unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"`), the `/` and the `?` can be used in the fragment directly (i.e., percent-encoding is not needed).

The `/` is even mentioned explicitly in the text:

> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") are allowed to represent data within the fragment identifier. Beware that some older, erroneous implementations may not handle this data correctly when it is used as the base URI for relative references (Section 5.1).

Answer (score 1):

Fragment can contain any character at all.

Query can contain any character except for `#`, as it is treated as marker (but you can use URL-encoding to still have it there)

So, in general, there are no any reserved characters as long as there is no ambiguity.

See [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) for the most up-to-date info. Your "general form" is not exactly right

Answer (score -1):

of course you can use `/` in both `fragment` and `query`

An example:

```
<a href='#vol/p'>hash example</a>

<div style='min-height:500px;'></div>
<div id='vol/p'>
    <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp?weep/sho/sdf=help'>get example</a>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/eLtJV/2)

Basically you can use anything that can be encoded in an URL.
[moreinfo](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1630.txt)