# What type of URL is "www.example.com/#/bar/1"?

Tags: url

I've seen few URLs of the form

```
www.example.com/#/bar/1
```

How would this URL be interpreted? As far as I know the `#` represents a fragment of the page, but here it looks completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is not a URL, as it misses a scheme. I’m assuming you mean `http` (or `https`), so the URL would be

```
http://www.example.com/#/bar/1
```

The (first) `#` starts the [fragment identifier component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5).

So `/bar/1` is the fragment of that URL. (The [`/` is allowed in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441627/1591669); see a [list of all allowed characters in the fragment identifier component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119120/1591669).)

It’s up to the site if and in which way to make use of this fragment. Commonly this URL design is used by sites that serve the content via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It's used for page reloading with a hash.

See Mozillas [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) for more information.